Where does this integral closure proof go wrong?
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2y-x)$, $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $S = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,...\}$.
Is $S^{-1}A$ integral over $S^{-1}R$? It is not, and I was made to see it was not since it would imply via some quotients that $Z[1/2]$ is integral over $Z$, which is not true. But I can't figure out the mistake in my "proof".
It is integral.  Let $p(x,y)/x^m$ be a representative of some element of $S^{-1}A$, where $n$ is the degree of $p(x,y)$. Consider $g(x)/x^{m+n}$, where $g(x)$ is some polynomial in $x$. Then $p(x,y)/x^m +  g(x)/x^{m+n} = (x^n p(x,y) + g(x) ) /x^{m+n}$. Now we can replace every $x$ in the polynomial representatives by $2y$, since they are equal in $A$, and we get $((2y)^n q(y) + g(2y)) / x^{m+n}$. There is a polynomial $g$ such that the numerator is zero, since the only restraint on $g(2y)$ is that the coefficient of $y^m$ is divisible by $2^m$, but that is also true for $(2y)^n q(y)$. So the sum of the elements is zero, and there is a monic polynomial equal to zero.

So, your element $z \in S^{-1}A$ is $z = \frac{p(x,y)}{x^m}$. What exactly is now the monic polynomial $f \in S^{-1}R[T]$ with $f(z) = 0$?

Was meant to be the element $z - g(x)/x^{m+n}$, but as Lucas pointed out that $g(x)$ may not always work.

I don't see why there needs to be a $g$ that makes the numerator $=0$. For example, $p(x, y) = y + y^2$, after multiplying by $x^2$ and substituting $x$ by $2y$ we get $4y^3 + 4y^4$. It is not possible to define a $g(x)$ such that $g(2y) = -(4y^3 + 4y^4)$ since $4$ is not a perfect cube.

$S^{-1}A$ is not integral over $S^{-1}R$:
It is $A \cong \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ and $R \cong \mathbb{Z}[2Y] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ and $S \cong \{1, 2Y, (2Y)^2, \dots\}$.
Claim: $Y$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}[2Y]_{2Y}$.
Otherwise there is some
$$f = T^n + \sum_{r = 0}^{n-1} \frac{f_r(2Y)}{(2Y)^{k_r}}T^r \in  \mathbb{Z}[2Y][T]$$
with $f_r(2Y) = a_{r,0} + 2Yg_r(2Y)$ for some $0\neq a_{r,0} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g_r \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ and
$$0 = f(Y) = Y^n + \sum_{r = 0}^{n-1}\frac{f_r(2Y)}{(2Y)^{k_r}}Y^r \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}[Y]_{2Y}.$$
Thus, with $l = \max_{i=1,\dots, n} k_i$ and $l_r = l -k_r$ and $f_n = 1$,
$$0 = \sum_{r = 0}^{n}(2Y)^{l_r}f_r(2Y)Y^r \text{ in }\mathbb{Z}[Y].$$
Let $I:= \{ r\in\{0,\dots,n\} \ | \  l_r = 0 \}$. Now reduce it modulo $2Y$ then
$$\bar 0 = \overline{\sum_{r = 0}^{n}(2Y)^{l_r}f_r(2Y)Y^r} = \overline{\sum_{r \in I}f_{r}(2Y)Y^{r}} =  \overline{\sum_{r \in I}(a_{r,0} +(2Y)g_{r}(2Y))Y^{r}} \\= \overline{\sum_{r \in I}a_{r,0}Y^{r}} \text{ in }\mathbb{Z}[Y]/(2Y).$$
It is $\mathbb{Z}[Y]/(2Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and therefore
$$ 0 = \sum_{r \in I}a_{r,0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{r} \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right].$$
which implies that $a_{r,0} = 0$ for all $r \in I$. Since $I \neq \emptyset$ this is a contradiction to $a_{r,0} \neq 0$ for all $r = 0,\dots,n$.
Thus $S^{-1}A$ is not integral over $S^{-1}R$.
